# Why am I getting "bash: javac: command not found" after supposedly installing jdk17.0.1 on Raspberry pi OS 64 bit?

Tags: pi-4, raspberry-pi-os, java, 64-bit

So I followed The instructions here
https://linuxhint.com/install-oracle-java-jdk-16-raspberry-pi/

Except I did so entirely on the gui of Raspberry pi OS. I downloaded the jdk file from the same website. I just didn't use any remote connections to run the commands. I also went with the newer LTS release jdk17.0.1

It seems to have been extracted to the right directory (/opt)

I wrote the path file in the nano text editor.

When I try to test it as described in the instructions using the terminal I get "bash: javac: command not found"

I'm running Raspberry Pi OS 64-bit. It's the last version of Buster. It's got the GUI.

I'm trying to make a Minecraft server for me and my brother using spigot and plan to turn off the gui when I'm done before running the server.

Can you guys help me solve this? Please be specific. I'm still pretty new to this stuff.

Thank you so much!

Comment: so `/opt/jdk-17.0.1/bin` exists? in the terminal, `PATH` includes `:/opt/jdk-17.0.1/bin` ?

Comment: Sorry about the delayed response. Yes /opt/jdk-17.0 .1/bin exists in my directories. I'm afraid I'm not sure what you mean by PATH though. Still pretty new to the command line interface.

Comment: and in the PATH?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure what you mean by PATH though. Still pretty new to the command line interface. One of the steps in the instructions mentioned typing "echo $PATH" in the terminal. I recieved the following...       /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/opt/jdk17.0.1/bin"

Comment: Sorry. Too many edits

Comment: Or do you mean the PATH file...? One moment please.

Comment: The file I made acording to the instructions has the following...

Comment: export JAVA_HOME="/opt/jdk17.0.1"

Comment: Followed by the ENTER key and...

Comment: export PATH="$PATH:${JAVA_HOME}/bin"

Comment: can you see the difference between `/opt/jdk17.0.1/bin` and `/opt/jdk-17.0.1/bin` - perhaps it's not obvious ... `jdk17` vs `jdk-17`

Comment: Yes. How embarrassing. Please wait...

Comment: It still seems to be giving me the same bash response about javac: command not found when I try to compile the test file.

Comment: Never mind! I rebooted. It's working now. Thank so much for your help!